# API Google Calendar insert ACL

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I use the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to interact with the Google API in my saas app to create a calendar.

I have already successfully integrated authentication with token refresh, calendar creation, creation/deletion and updating of events.

I am now trying to share the calendar with other users this way (following the example in the api doc)

```
$scope = new AclRuleScope();
$scope->setType('user');
$scope->setValue('email@test.com');

$rule = new AclRule();
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole('reader');

$result = $this->acl->insert('my-google-calendar-id', $rule);
```

and the response of the call to insert is

```
                              
  {                           
   "error": {                 
    "errors": [               
     {                        
      "domain": "global",     
      "reason": "notFound",   
      "message": "Not Found"  
     }                        
    ],                        
    "code": 404,              
    "message": "Not Found"    
   }                          
  }
```

I ran the insert in the google developers console and it worked correctly.
I checked that 'google-calendar-id' exists with a get method.
I also set up a retries system with a sleep but without success, I still have the same error.
The scopes used for authorizations are `Calendar::CALENDAR, Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS`

Has anyone ever had this problem ? What am I doing wrong ?